# How to fix a SIGSEGV in pytorch when using distributed training (e.g. DDP)?

Tags: python, neural-network, multiprocessing, pytorch, distributed-computing

I keep getting this issue when running DDP in pytorch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 330, in <module>
    main_distributed()
  File "ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 230, in main_distributed
    mp.spawn(fn=train, args=(opts,), nprocs=opts.world_size)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 199, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 157, in start_processes
    while not context.join():
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in join
    raise Exception(
Exception: process 1 terminated with signal SIGSEGV
```

but this error is rather uninformative (dones't tell me what process or what it was trying to access for example) so I am unsure what I need to do do solve it.

[Some research](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016786#:%7E:text=On%20a%20Unix%20operating%20system,memory%20address%20that%20does%20not) takes you that:

> SIGSEGV: On a Unix operating system such as Linux, a "segmentation violation" (also known as "signal 11", "SIGSEGV", "segmentation fault" or, abbreviated, "sig11" or "segfault") is a signal sent by the kernel to a process when the system has detected that the process was attempting to access a memory address that does not belong to it. Typically, this results in the offending process being terminated.

yes I do have multiprocessing code as the usual `mp.spawn(fn=train, args=(opts,), nprocs=opts.world_size)` requires.

First I read the docs on [sharing strategies](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html#sharing-strategies) which talks about how tensors are shared in pytorch:

> Note that it applies only to CPU tensor - CUDA tensors will always use the CUDA API, as that’s the only way they can be shared.

I was using the [file system sharing memory](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html#file-system-file-system) since it seemed to give me less issue when I needed lots of processes but I went down to only 2 processes and 2 gpus and to the share strategy being [file descriptor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html#file-system-file-system). I thought that perhaps if the processes had their own cached file descriptor then there wouldn't be issues.

I did check the cuda devices availabe:

```
 $ echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
1,3
```

all seems fine.

I am unsure what might be causing the issue. There are possible issues like:

- two processes are trying to checkpoint at the same time but I always only let `rank=0` do the checkpointing so that doesn't make sense.
- two processes are writing to tensorboard but I also only allow `rank=0` to do the logging (or any of the printing).

So I am unsure what could be causing the issue. It could be that I have my dataset concatenated all 1 single json file causing the issue, but that wasn't causing issues yesterday with multiple gpus...though, if that is the case it would be hard to fix since [DDP (distributed data parallel)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel) uses the [DistributedSampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler) which doesn't place any restriction like that on my data-set or dataloaders...or at least as far as I know (afaik).

Last thing is that yesterday I was getting weird error too and somehow it occurred to me to check the gpu type. I was quetting an issue because I was using a k40 gpu. I made sure that was not the case. Yesterday I was using a `Quadro 6000 RTX`, today it seems these are the GPUs I got:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar  2 12:15:04 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 450.36.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   37C    P0    56W / 250W |      0MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 24%   39C    P0    56W / 250W |      0MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:82:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 53%   84C    P2   244W / 250W |  11935MiB / 12196MiB |     57%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 25%   39C    P0    56W / 250W |      0MiB / 12196MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    2   N/A  N/A     31809      C   python                          11933MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

not sure if that is causing the issue but it's not always realistic to get the Quadro's so I want it to work for the Titan's too (and anything that isn't the k40s since the k40s seem to not be supported by pytorch anymore).

There are a few pytorch discussion forum posts and gitissues but none seems very helpful (to me at lest - not clear what they did to solve things despite end of discussion):

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiprocessing-using-torch-multiprocessing/11029/3
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-torch-tensor-over-multiprocessing-queue-process-fails/2847/12
- https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/issues/1720
- https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/issues/1308
- https://github.com/facebookresearch/SlowFast/issues/118
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/segmentation-fault/23489

I also noticed this happens when rank 0 ends before rank 1 (that helped me reproduce it, otherwise a sigabort `SIGABRT` happens).

```
    # clean up distributed code
    torch.distributed.barrier()
    if rank == 1:
        time.sleep(1)
    print(f'\n----> about to cleanup worker with rank {rank}')
    # cleanup(rank)
    torch.distributed.destroy_process_group()
    print(f'clean up done successfully! {rank}'
```

---

crossposted:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-fix-a-sigsegv-in-pytorch-when-using-distributed-training-e-g-ddp/113518
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/lwbb72/how_to_fix_a_sigsegv_in_pytorch_when_using/
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-fix-a-SIGSEGV-in-PyTorch-when-using-distributed-training-e-g-DDP